# Write the elements of an array to file where each element is on its own line in Fortran

Tags: fortran, format

I wrote some code to print out the elements of a 3d-array where each element of the array is printed to a new line on screen. That worked (see output below).

Can anyone help me write a format statement that can produce the same thing in a file?  (i.e. using `WRITE(*,1200)` and `1200 FORMAT()` etc)?

Here is my code:

```
PROGRAM test_3d_array
IMPLICIT NONE
integer :: matrix(3,3,3), i, j, k ! three dimensional real array
integer :: CORE, CON, ALPHA

CORE = 3
CON = 3
ALPHA = 3

!assigning some values to the array matrix
   do i=1,ALPHA
      do j = 1,CORE
         do k = 1,CON
         matrix(i, j, k) = i+j+k
      end do
   end do
end do

   !display the values
   do i=1,ALPHA
      do j = 1, CORE
         do k=1,CON
         WRITE(*,*) "MATRIX (", i, ",", j, ",", k, ") = ", matrix(i,j,k)
      end do
   end do
end do

END PROGRAM test_3d_array
```

Here is the screen output that I want to reproduce in the file:

```
 MATRIX (           1 ,           1 ,           1 ) =            3
 MATRIX (           1 ,           1 ,           2 ) =            4
 MATRIX (           1 ,           1 ,           3 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           1 ,           2 ,           1 ) =            4
 MATRIX (           1 ,           2 ,           2 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           1 ,           2 ,           3 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           1 ,           3 ,           1 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           1 ,           3 ,           2 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           1 ,           3 ,           3 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           2 ,           1 ,           1 ) =            4
 MATRIX (           2 ,           1 ,           2 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           2 ,           1 ,           3 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           2 ,           2 ,           1 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           2 ,           2 ,           2 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           2 ,           2 ,           3 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           2 ,           3 ,           1 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           2 ,           3 ,           2 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           2 ,           3 ,           3 ) =            8
 MATRIX (           3 ,           1 ,           1 ) =            5
 MATRIX (           3 ,           1 ,           2 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           3 ,           1 ,           3 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           3 ,           2 ,           1 ) =            6
 MATRIX (           3 ,           2 ,           2 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           3 ,           2 ,           3 ) =            8
 MATRIX (           3 ,           3 ,           1 ) =            7
 MATRIX (           3 ,           3 ,           2 ) =            8
 MATRIX (           3 ,           3 ,           3 ) =            9
```

Comment: Do you want to reproduce the output exactly? i.e. exactly the same spacing?

Comment: No, just each line having the index of the element and also the element value

Comment: If you want to write the output as you have it to a file, then why can't you just write to a file with, say, `write(134,*) ...`? Why do you want to also use a `format` statement (noting that `write(*,1200) ...` will still write to the same place)?